# Is there a way to extract DialogFlow 'today' as the past 24 hours?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have training phrases like:

- How many customers visited my website in the past 24 hours?
- How many people visited in the past 6 hours?
- How many customers visited my website today?

I understand that for @sys.date-time, I am able to extract "past 6hours" and "past 24hours" as a date-time period with a startDate and endDate. However, for "today", I receive a singular date. 
Is there a way to (through custom entities, etc) to parse "today" as a time-period too with startDate:  and endDate: <24hours earlier>?

Ultimately, I am trying to create a chatbot that requires passing a time period (startDate & endDate) to my external API during fulfillment, so I won't be able to work with singular dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*sys.time-period* and *sys.date-period* entities does not accept today as a valid value.

So what you can do is create a [composite custom entity](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-options#comp), lets say with name **myDateTimeRange** and with value **@sys.date-time:dateTime**. When this entity is matched a json object will be returned and that's the trick here. Now this entity can give you result for both date-time and time-range, for example if the matched text is today then you will get the value of myDateTimeRange entity as **{ "dateTime": "2020-06-02T12:00:00+05:30" }** and if the matched text is a range like **past 6hours** then the returned value will be like **{ "dateTime": { "endDateTime": "2020-06-02T12:12:10+05:30", "startDateTime": "2020-06-02T06:12:10+05:30" } }**.

So now you can easily create some logic based on the returned value, like if you received only dateTime that means some date is entered (like today) and you can take it as both start date and end date, but if you get endDateTime and startDateTime sub properties also then you know you have received a range.

Note that you can improve your composite entity by adding more values to it like **@sys.time-period:timePeriod**, **@sys.date-period:datePeriod**, etc.

Comment: Thank you! With regards to improving my composite entity by adding more values, could you give me an example of how I could do so in my example? I have tried adding values sys.time-period:timePeriod and sys.date-period:datePeriod but queries get matched to date-time anyway. How exactly does adding these values help to improve the composite entity?

Comment: Nothing specific. I just added that to give you a direction to explore, in case your requirement is not fulfilled by dateTime.